# Update table from other table with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you help me
I want to write sql command to update column (UpdValue) for table tblB 
use key (ID) with condition [the latest (Date,Time) of tblA]
Thanks

[Click here to view Image detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDbG4.png)

[image]

Comment: You (or the website on your behalf) tagged this as SQL, but your illustration looks like Excel. No problem with that, except that Oracle does not have date and time datatypes, it only has a combined datetime datatype. So, what do YOU have? An excel spreadsheet, or Oracle tables?

Comment: Thank you. I use Oracle Table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is properly set up in Oracle, maybe this is what you want:

```
update tblB 
   set UpdValue = (select UpdValue 
                   from tblA a 
                   where a.ID = tblB.ID 
                   and a.date_time = (select max(date_time) from tblA x where x.ID = a.ID)
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't write max(date_time) with 2 column: Date and Time

Comment: Please explain how you can have two columns, date and time, in an Oracle table. Are they both of data type date? (The Oracle type "date" which has both date and time components?) Give an example of exactly what is stored in the two columns, for one row. Please don't answer something like "2016-05-24" and "09:30:00" - there is no such thing in Oracle. (Or are they stored as strings, like varchar2, not date?)